# ngInfiniteScroll not working with li

Tags: angularjs, infinite-scroll

ng-scroll is not working with the inner tag.But working with the window scroll.

This is my code.

*Example*

```
        <div id="vlist" style ="height:50%;width:100%;">
           <ul infinite-scroll="loadMoreVariables()" infinite-scroll-distance="2"  infinite-scroll-container="'#vlist'" style="overflow: auto;height:250px;width:100%;float:left;margin:0px;">
            <li ng-repeat="variable in variables" style ="line-height: 1.5em;white-space: nowrap;padding-top: 0.25em;">
                <a style="text-decoration: none;font-size: inherit;color: inherit;cursor: pointer;">{{variable.measure}};{{variable.displayName}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

what can be a issue in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the style="overflow: auto;" on the element you have defined in the infinite-scroll-container attribute (#vlist).